# Best/efficient way to search a large csv in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, csv, search

I have a somewhat large csv file that has 1.5K entries. Each entry represents a city around the globe with a name, latitude, and longitude. What's the best and fast way to go about searching through the csv in Java? I wanted to populate an ArrayList with all the entries but I think its slow (unless I'm wrong). No this file won't grow in size, its almost 100KB. I'd like to be able to enter the name of the city and update search results; but this I can figure out on my own.

Comment: Populate an `ArrayList` (once), and then re-use it.

Comment: Or use a `HashMap`, if you want to quickly get info given an exact city name.

Comment: 1.5K entries? You could grow that a couple of orders of magnitude and I'm still not sure I'd classify it as somewhat large! (Also, you seem worried about performance but aren't giving us any figures - what's the approximate documented performance requirement we need to aim for here?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 1.5K entries files of about 1 MB should take tens of milli-seconds. A 1 GB file could takes tens of seconds and it might be worth saving an index for this file to save having to re-read it each time.

You can load into a Map to have an index by `name`

You can add a latitude and longitude index via a NavigableMap. This will speed up lookups by location.

Loading the file once takes a little time, however reading the file from disk each time is much slower.

BTW You can have 100s TB of data with trillions of rows, to use this data in Java you have to get creative.

In short, if its much less than you have memory, it's relatively small file.

Answer (score 3):

1.5K rows of city-name, latitude, and longitude is *not* a somewhat large file, it is *quite a small file*, and it hardly matters how you read it, as long as you don't do anything completely unreasonable, such as reading it a byte at a time using unbuffered I/O.

So, what I'd do in your shoes is that I would go ahead and read the file one line at a time, construct row objects, and add them to an `ArrayList`.  This will probably be fast enough that you can throw away the list after each search, and reload it each time you want to search.  Or you might of course want to keep it if you don't mind occupying some memory.

But in any case, I would only worry about performance if, for some unfathomable reason, performance turns out to be a problem in the end.  You have not told us what are the performance requirements of the product you are making.  Without performance requirements, and without measurements, all talk about performance is usually unreasonable fears and tend to result in premature optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest CSV parser for this would be [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial). There are many ways to approach this problem, the following is flexible enough to give you results at a decent speed. The following example uses a 150MB CSV file with 1.3 million rows, and runs the search in ~1 second:

#### First, create a `RowProcessor`

Here we extend one of the existing ones that come with the library, the

```
public class CsvSearch extends RowListProcessor {
    //value to be searched for
    private final String stringToMatch;

    //name of column to match (if you don't have headers)
    private final String columnToMatch;

    //position of column to match
    private int indexToMatch = -1;

    public CsvSearch(String columnToMatch, String stringToMatch){
        this.columnToMatch = columnToMatch;
        this.stringToMatch = stringToMatch.toLowerCase(); //lower case to make the search case-insensitive
    }

    public CsvSearch(int columnToMatch, String stringToMatch){
        this(stringToMatch, null);
        this.indexToMatch = columnToMatch;
    }

    @Override
    public void rowProcessed(String[] row, ParsingContext context) {
        if(indexToMatch == -1) {
            //initializes the index to match
            indexToMatch = context.indexOf(columnToMatch);
        }

        String value = row[indexToMatch];
        if(value != null && value.toLowerCase().contains(stringToMatch)) {
            super.rowProcessed(row, context); // default behavior of the RowListProcessor: add the row into a List.
        }
        // else skip the row.
    }
}
```

#### Configure the parser and run

```
// let's measure the time roughly
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); //extract headers from the first row

CsvSearch search = new CsvSearch("City", "Paris");

//We instruct the parser to send all rows parsed to your custom RowProcessor.
settings.setProcessor(search);

//Finally, we create a parser
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

//And parse! All rows are sent to your custom RowProcessor (CsvSearch)
//I'm using a 150MB CSV file with 1.3 million rows.
parser.parse(new File("/tmp/data/worldcitiespop.txt"));

//get the collected rows from our processor
List<String[]> results = search.getRows();

//Nothing else to do. The parser closes the input and does everything for you safely. Let's just get the results:
System.out.println("Rows matched: " + results.size());
System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
```

This produced the following output on my computer (a 2015 MacBook Pro):

```
Rows matched: 218
Time taken: 997 ms
```

The results returned look like this:

```
[af, parisang, Parisang, 08, null, 33.180704, 67.470836]
[af, qaryeh-ye bid-e parishan, Qaryeh-ye Bid-e Parishan, 06, null, 33.242727, 63.389834]
[ar, parish, Parish, 01, null, -36.518335, -59.633313]
[at, parisdorf, Parisdorf, 03, null, 48.566667, 15.85]
[au, paris creek, Paris Creek, 05, null, -35.216667, 138.8]
[az, hayi paris, Hayi Paris, 21, null, 40.449626, 46.55542]
[az, hay paris, Hay Paris, 21, null, 40.449626, 46.55542]
[az, rousi paris, Rousi Paris, 21, null, 40.435789, 46.510691]
[az, rrusi paris, Rrusi Paris, 21, null, 40.435789, 46.510691]
[bb, parish land, Parish Land, 01, null, 13.0666667, -59.5166667]
... (and many more)
```

The speed can be further improved if you select the columns to be parsed, and ignore whatever you don't need. Just call `settings.selectFields("City");` before processing the file to instruct the parser to generate `Strings` only for the `City` column.

Hope this helps.
Disclosure: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache v2.0 license)

Answer (score -3):

When you deal with large text content, you might need to do some text manipulation.

Be aware of the string concatenation. Usually use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` to concat strings.